# How do you pronounce "would've", "should've" and "could've"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

How do you pronounce "would've", "should've" and "could've"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IPA, that's

would've - /wʊdəv/ - WOULD-uhv
should've - /ʃʊdəv/ - SHOULD-uhv
could've - /kʊdəv/ - COULD-uhv

where "uhv" is a [schwa sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) followed by a V sound.

Frequently, in fast or informal speech, the V sound will be [elided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) (omitted), and the results will sound like "would-a", "should-a", "could-a".

**Edit**: I will note that “woulda, shoulda, coulda” (and the same words in different orders) is a very informal idiom that refers dismissively to regretting missed opportunities. The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/) has about 23 examples of all three of them used together, mostly in fiction and spoken English, but also in quoted speech in a few newspaper and magazine articles.

Comment: Yup, and that’s why I have seen (far too many) illiterates on the Internet actually write `would of, should of, could of`. `:-|`

Answer (score 4):

wood-uv, shud-uv, cud-uv.

Answer (score 3):

If you listen closely, sometimes you'll hear me say "wooda". However, I usually say "wood'-uv" with the second syllable very abbreviated.

The pronunciation leads to a common spelling error: *would of*.

Comment: "would of" makes me want to claw my eyes out sometimes.